# Function for balance interest

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have the following dataframe `df1`:

```
Bank           Rate_1Y%
Bank of America    2
Barclays          0.75
Nationalbanken    0.05
Deutsche Bank      0
UBS              -0.75
```

I have the following dataframe `df2`:

```
                0
2010-12-31  2010-12-31
2011-12-31  2011-12-31
2012-12-31  2012-12-31
2013-12-31  2013-12-31
2014-12-31  2014-12-31
2015-12-31  2015-12-31
2016-12-31  2016-12-31
2017-12-31  2017-12-31
2018-12-31  2018-12-31
2019-12-31  2019-12-31
```

I have an input values:

```
Input_Balance = 10000

Start_Date = '2010-01-01'

End_Date = '2020-01-01'

freq = '1Y'
```

I created new df2 with time column:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2010-12-31', '2011-12-31', '2012-12-31', '2013-12-31',
           '2014-12-31', '2015-12-31', '2016-12-31', '2017-12-31',
           '2018-12-31', '2019-12-31'],
          dtype='datetime64[ns]
```

Can anyone help to find a simple function solution for calculating Input_Balance change, for period which represented as `End_Date - Start_Date`.
I want to have a new column in df2 which represents end balance calculation for custom banks, in this case i use Bank of America.

Expected Output:

```
  Date        End Balance
2010-12-31     10200$
2011-12-31     10200$
2012-12-31     10200$
```

There is need to write down in a column end balance for custom banks, for selected periods (start period to end period)

Comment: What columns have the df2? is there only data index cols? or End_Date and Start_Date are also present, am I right?

Comment: @Cindy yes, df2 is absolutely clear dataframe, and include only datd index col. Start & End date is selection in df2 index

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If I understood the OP's problem correctly, and that each row of `df2` should correspond to the current balance at time t given an initial balance at `Start_Date`, then I would go this way:

```py
from datetime import datetime, timedelta


def compute_balance(input_balance, 
                    prev_date, 
                    end_date, 
                    time_interval, 
                    rate_by_bank, 
                    data=None, 
                    ):
    """
    Recursively compute balance at time t given yearly rate
    :param input_balance: initial input balance (x0)
    :param prev_date: datetime.datetime object specifying starting date
    :param end_date: datetime.datetime object specifying ending date
    :param time_interval: time interval in days
    :param rate_by_bank: a dictionary providing change rate per bank {bank_name: rate, ...}
    :param data: List of dictionary (must not be set by user)

    :return pandas.DataFrame
    """

    if data is None:
        data = [{
            'time': prev_date,
            **{
                bank_name: input_balance
                for bank_name, _ in rate_by_bank
              }
        }]

    nb_days_per_year = 365.0
    normalized_time_interval = time_interval/nb_days_per_year
    cur_date = prev_date + timedelta(days=time_interval)

    if cur_date >= end_date:
        return pd.DataFrame(data).set_index('time')

    balance_per_bank = {
        bank_name: (data[-1][bank_name] 
                    + (rate/100.0) * normalized_time_interval * data[-1][bank_name]
                   )
        for bank_name, rate in rate_by_bank
    }
    data.append({
        'time': cur_date,
        **balance_per_bank
    })
    return compute_balance(input_balance, cur_date, end_date, time_interval, rates, data)


# Input variables
Input_Balance = 10000
Start_Date = '2010-01-01'
End_Date = '2020-01-01'

# convert df_1 to dictionary to get rate per bank
rates = df_1.to_dict(orient='split')['data']

# convert dates to datetime objects
start_date = pd.Timestamp(datetime.strptime(Start_Date, '%Y-%d-%m'))
end_date = pd.Timestamp(datetime.strptime(End_Date, '%Y-%d-%m'))

df_2 = compute_balance(Input_Balance, start_date, end_date, 365, rates)
```

Which should then output:

```
            Bank of America      Barclays  Deutsche Bank  NationalBanken  \
time                                                                       
2010-01-01       10000.0000  10000.000000        10000.0    10000.000000   
2011-01-01       10200.0000  10075.000000        10000.0    10005.000000   
2012-01-01       10404.0000  10150.562500        10000.0    10010.002500   
2012-12-31       10612.0800  10226.691719        10000.0    10015.007501   
2013-12-31       10824.3216  10303.391907        10000.0    10020.015005   

                     UBS  
time                      
2010-01-01  10000.000000  
2011-01-01   9925.000000  
2012-01-01   9850.562500  
2012-12-31   9776.683281  
2013-12-31   9703.358157
```

Comment: that was brilliant, level of your understanding = magic, thanks a lot !! @FlorianP

Comment: Wow top answer mate, will come back to this i'm sure.

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you need to recursively add the interest to the current value?

I assume that df will contain the interest rate and banks,

and that df2 will have the start date.

then we could do a cartesian product to create a new df then apply a loop to work on the rows.

```
# cartesian product.
df3 = (
            df.assign(key=1)
            .merge(df2.assign(key=1), on="key")
            .drop("key", axis=1)
        )

#Get indices of first instance of each bank. Assuming your data is ordered by datetime.
indices = df3.drop_duplicates(subset='Bank',keep='first').index.tolist()

# calculate the first interest value.
df3.loc[indices,'Value'] = value + (value * (df3['Rate_1Y%'] / 100))

# Calculate the rest of the data frame.
for i in range(1, len(df3)):
    df3.loc[i, 'Value'] = df3.loc[i-1, 'Value'] + (df3.loc[i-1, 'Value'] * (df3.loc[i, 'Rate_1Y%'] / 100))

print(df3)

               Bank  Rate_1Y%        Date         Value
0   Bank of America      2.00  2010-12-31  10200.000000
1   Bank of America      2.00  2011-12-31  10404.000000
2   Bank of America      2.00  2012-12-31  10612.080000
3   Bank of America      2.00  2013-12-31  10824.321600
4   Bank of America      2.00  2014-12-31  11040.808032
5   Bank of America      2.00  2015-12-31  11261.624193
6   Bank of America      2.00  2016-12-31  11486.856676
7   Bank of America      2.00  2017-12-31  11716.593810
8   Bank of America      2.00  2018-12-31  11950.925686
9   Bank of America      2.00  2019-12-31  12189.944200
```

as a function, feel free to change edit as your needs.

```
def calc_interest(dataframe_1, dataframe_2, col_name='Rate_1Y%'):
   df3 = (
   dataframe_1.assign(key=1)
   .merge(dataframe_2.assign(key=1), on="key")
   .drop("key", axis=1)
 ) 

   indices = df3.drop_duplicates(subset='Bank',keep='first').index.tolist()

   df3.loc[indices,'Value'] = value + (value * (df3[col_name] / 100))

   for i in range(1, len(df3)):
        df3.loc[i, 'Value'] = df3.loc[i-1, 'Value'] + (df3.loc[i-1, 'Value'] * (df3.loc[i, 'Rate_1Y%'] / 100))
```

Comment: Great solution for simple analyse, it is a pure answer of question. But this great guy FlorianP gived a full solution even for my next steps. Any way thanks a lot too @Datanovoice

Comment: @ArtemReznov no problem and many thanks for your upvote :) i agree this answer is ace.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to create new column in `df2`, just write:

```
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

df2.reset_index(name='Start_Date', inplace=True)

df2['End_Date'] = '2020-01-01' #or any required value

df2['Start_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['Start_Date'])
df2['End_Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df2['End_Date'])

df2['Input_Balance'] = df2['End_Date']- df2['Start_Date']
```

If you need to create new column for custom bank, it means that name of Bank should be in df2 too. Another way it in usage `groupby` with aggregation.

It would be great to have examples of `df1`, `df2` and clear expected result in view of `df2`...

Comment: edited topic, results must be in function, for simple further use